# getting "No value given for one or more required parameters."

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007

I have created a registration page and linked it to Access database now I'm trying to use the information stored on the Db to  use on login page but keep getting this "No value given for one or more required parameters." error.

```
protected void loginButtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connect = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Wisal\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\WebSites\WebSite3\registration-Db.mdb";       
    string query = "Select Count(*) From client Where [name] = ? And  surname = ? and [password] = ?";
    int result = 1;
    using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("", nameloginBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" ", snameloginBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" ", passwrdloginBox.Text);
            conn.Open();
            Session["User"] = nameloginBox.Text;
            result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        }   
    }
    if (result > 0)
    {
        Response.Redirect("general.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Literal1.Text = "Invalid credentials";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you setting the value of three parameters when you only have two in the query?

Comment: thanks for pointing out totally missed that one. I have changed the string query however i'm not getting redirected but the login page redirects but the response.redirect is pointing to ("general.aspx") any idea why? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Rob commented (beat me to it), you are passing 3 parameters **with no name**. Your code should look something like this, so Access knows what parameters correspond to what variable.

```
string query = "Select Count(*) From client Where Username = ? And UserPassword = ?";
int result = 1;
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connect))
{
    using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Username", snameloginBox.Text); //username parameter
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("UserPassword", passwrdloginBox.Text); //userpassword parameter
        conn.Open();
        Session["User"] = nameloginBox.Text;
        result = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }   
}
```

For further information about passing parameters to Access queries, [please reed here](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/26/parameter-queries-in-asp-net-with-ms-access).

Comment: yes your absolutely right i have made a change to the string query but the redirect does not work as the page only refreshes itself

Comment: it worked thank you it was all the string query that caused the problem. Much appreciated!